# Unable to connect samsung device to pc

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop

I'm having problem connecting my device(Samsung j7) to my laptop via USB port. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please be specific as to what you've tried and what behavior you're seeing.

Comment: can u understand it now @MatthewRead ?

Comment: I had no trouble understanding it.  We need you to be specific about what the problem is -- "problem connecting USB" could be any one of a dozen unrelated issues.  And as mentioned above, we need details about what you are seeing and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this solution and it worked!

1. Go to dial pad & type *#0808#
2. It displays USB settings
3. Select MTP+ADB option
4. Press OK button
5. Connect to USB cable to PC
6. It shows Connected as a media device.